# why is there no function $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is continious precisely at the point of $ D$?

Tags: general-topology

Source: Munkre Topology   Chapter  $8$ Baire space ,Excercise $7$

**Theorem** :If  $D $ is  a  countable  dense   subset  of $\mathbb{R}$,there is  no function $ f: \mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R}$   that is  continious   precisely  at  the  point  of $ D$

Im  not  getting  this theorem  because if we take $D= \mathbb{Q}$  and  take $f(x)=x $  then $ f: \mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R}$   that is  continious   precisely  at  the  point  of $ \mathbb{Q}$

I think  above  theorem is not true for  all functions

Also ,i think this  theorem  is valid  for  some   function like $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)=\begin{cases} 1 \  x\in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0  \  x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}  \end{cases} $

**My question** :why  is there   no function $ f: \mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R}$   that is  continious   precisely  at  the  point  of $ D$?

Comment: 'continuous precisely at' means continuous at the point of $D$ and discontinuous at the point of $\mathbb{R} - D$.

Comment: okay @Mockingbird

Comment: 1)  Set of continuity $G_{\delta}$ set . $\\$2) Dense $G_{\delta}$ subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is of $2$nd category $\\$3) A second category subset of $\Bbb{R}$ contains an interval. $\\$4) An interval is uncountable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They said "continuous precisely at the points of $\mathbb{Q}$". So, $f$ must ONLY be continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$. The function $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$ that you gave is not continuous anywhere. Indeed, let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ be fixed. Assume that $x_0$ is rational. Then, $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x_0) = 1$.

Now, find an irrational sequence that converges to $x_0$, call it $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Then, $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(y_n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If this were continuous, then:
$$0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(y_n) = \chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x_0) = 1$$
and that is impossible. A similar argument works when $x_0$ is irrational. As for your actual question, you said that this is a theorem in a book so you should elaborate on what you mean when you ask "Why is [blank] true?". That is, there's going to be a proof in the book so if you want a good answer to that, then you should elaborate on what you found difficult to understand.